# How do I create a simple HTML that would allow me to put in data and come up with a command later that I could copy?

Tags: javascript

I need something that would simplify my work. I am thinking of just having a form based HTML where I can input data and with a click of a button allow me to have a code to show the commands and I should be able to copy it.

Unfortunately what I tried below with alerts is not working.

```
<html>
<head>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 function ExampleJS(){
    var LDAPGroupOU = document.getElementById("ldap").value;
    var poolmin = document.getElementById("pmin").value;
    var poolmax = document.getElementById("pmax").value;
    alert("ip local pool " + LDAPGroupOU + "-pool" + " " + poolmin + "-" + poolmax + " " + "mask 255.255.255.255" + "\n" + "tunnel-group " +  LDAPGroupOU + "-profile type remote-access" + "\n" + "tunnel-group " +  LDAPGroupOU + "-profile general-attributes" + "\n" + "  address-pool " + LDAPGroupOU + "-pool" + "\n" + "  authentication-server-group RADIUS" + "\n" + "tunnel-group " + LDAPGroupOU + "-profile webvpn-attributes" + "\n" + "authentication aaa certificate" + "\n" + "pre-fill-username ssl-client" + "\n" + "exit" + "\n" + "crypto ca certificate map" + " " + LDAPGroupOU + "-map 10" + "\n" + "  subject-name attr ou eq " + LDAPGroupOU+ "\n" + "exit" + "\n" + "webvpn" + "\n" + "certificate-group-map " + LDAPGroupOU + "-map 10 " + " " + LDAPGroupOU + "-profile" + "\n" + "end"  + "\n" + "wr" );
 }
 </script>

</head>
<body>
    <FORM NAME="myform" onSubmit="JavaScript:ExampleJS()">
            xCVPN Code Generator <br />
            <br />
         Customer LDAP Group: <input type="text" id="ldap" name="firstname" /><br />
         Minimum Pool:  <input type="text" id="pmin" name="lastname" /><br />
         Maximum Pool:  <input type="text" id="pmax" name="lastname" /><br />
        <input name="Submit"  type="submit" value="Generate" />
    </FORM>
</body>
```

Comment: What isn't working? What's the expected result and what are you getting instead? Are there any errors?

Comment: Hello, actually it's like how Pak Wah Wong has below. I was looking for a way where I can just input the details then it generates the commands for me to copy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this:

```js
function ExampleJS() {
  var LDAPGroupOU = document.getElementById("ldap").value;
  var poolmin = document.getElementById("pmin").value;
  var poolmax = document.getElementById("pmax").value;
  var copy = document.getElementById("copy");
  copy.textContent = "ip local pool " + LDAPGroupOU + "-pool" + " " + poolmin + "-" + poolmax + " " + "mask 255.255.255.255" + "\n" + "tunnel-group " + LDAPGroupOU + "-profile type remote-access" + "\n" + "tunnel-group " + LDAPGroupOU + "-profile general-attributes" + "\n" + "  address-pool " + LDAPGroupOU + "-pool" + "\n" + "  authentication-server-group RADIUS" + "\n" + "tunnel-group " + LDAPGroupOU + "-profile webvpn-attributes" + "\n" + "authentication aaa certificate" + "\n" + "pre-fill-username ssl-client" + "\n" + "exit" + "\n" + "crypto ca certificate map" + " " + LDAPGroupOU + "-map 10" + "\n" + "  subject-name attr ou eq " + LDAPGroupOU + "\n" + "exit" + "\n" + "webvpn" + "\n" + "certificate-group-map " + LDAPGroupOU + "-map 10 " + " " + LDAPGroupOU + "-profile" + "\n" + "end" + "\n" + "wr";
  copy.select();

  /* Copy the text inside the text field */
  document.execCommand("copy");
}
```

```css
#copy {
  height: 300px;
  width: 500px;
}
```

```html
xCVPN Code Generator <br />
<br /> Customer LDAP Group: <input type="text" id="ldap" name="firstname" /><br /> Minimum Pool: <input type="text" id="pmin" name="lastname" /><br /> Maximum Pool: <input type="text" id="pmax" name="lastname" /><br />
<input name="Submit" type="button" onClick="ExampleJS()" value="Generate" />
<br />
<textarea id="copy"></textarea>
```

Comment: Thanks Mr Wong! This is exactly what I needed.+1 to you!  I did try copy and paste it in my HTML file but when I open it, blank. Sorry but I am new to these kind of coding...